# R: Help writing complex if-statements/for-loops to extract and tabulate elephant behavior

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements, apply

I am currently working on research related to post-conflict behavior in social male elephants. I am trying to drastically speed up some data extraction and processing. My data is in the following form:

```
Time = c(100, 120, 140, 440, 520, 650, 750) #time is in seconds
Individual1 = c("Luke", "Luke", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Tyler", "Luke")
Action = c("Over shoulder", "Displacement", "Trunk", "Trunk to mouth", "Tail swing", "Ears held out", "Trunk")
Individual2 = c("Tyler", "Tyler", "own mouth", "Luke", "Tyler", "Tyler", "own mouth")

df = data.frame(Time, Individual1, Action, Individual2)
```

I am interested in tabulating the behavioral data of the victim of aggression in a 10-minute window following a conflict. The aggressive behavior, in this case, is "Displacement", i.e. Luke-Displacement-Tyler.

I would like to do the following set of operations: 
From the time of a displacement between two individuals (in this case **120s**), I want to **count forward 600 seconds (10 minutes)** and tabulate all actions performed by **Individual2** at the time of displacement (in this case Tyler) until the end of that 10-minute window and who those actions are directed at (whatever is in the Individual2 column). Most events consist of hundreds of interactions between individuals and many displacements.

Is this a job for an "apply"-related function? A for-loop that includes a "table" call combined with some conditional subsetting commands?

UPDATE:

Thanks to Maiasaura's guidance below I've managed to mold the series of commands and functions to achieve the list of dataframes that I need. However, I am having trouble with one last part of this that combines mutate() with an ifelse() statement. My final goal is to look at the post-conflict interactions generated by the function below and determine if the "Action" column of the dataframe contains any of the affiliative behaviors below.

```
affiliation <- c("Trunk to body", "Other body","Head to head", 
"Trunk to  mouth","Rubs", "Gentle sparing", "Trunk to head", "Head to body",
"Trunk temperal", "Ear on face","Tail to body", "Trunk wrap", "Ear on rear",
"greeting")
```

Here is the function, edited from Maiasaura's code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

hostility <- c("Displacement", "Head shake", "Open mouth", "Head held up", 
"Trunk throw", "Chase", "Charge", "Head thrust", "Ear Fold", "Stand off",
"Lunge", "Aggressive ear flap", "Ears held out")

pos <- which(event$Action %in% hostility)

grab_data <- function(pos) {
  i2 <- as.character(event[pos, ]$Individual2)
  i1 <- as.character(event[pos, ]$Individual1)
  action <- as.character(event[pos, ]$Action)
  start <- event[pos, ]$Time
  df2 <- event %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Time > start) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Time <= (start + 600)) %>%
  dplyr::filter((Individual1 == i2 & Individual2 == i1) | (Individual1 == i1 &
  Individual2 == i2)) %>%
  mutate(Displaced = i2, OriginalDisplacer = i1, OriginalConflict = start, 
       Aggression = action, PCAff = ifelse(action %in% affiliation), "1","NA")
  df2
}

df2 <- map(pos, grab_data)
```

When I apply the function, however, I get the following warning:

*Error: argument "no" is missing, with no default*

This is related to the ifelse statement nested in the last mutate() command. What am I missing here? Do I need to provide the ifelse with an additional argument when the conditions aren't met? Thanks in advance for any R wisdom!

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? A list of tables, each associated w an event in `df`? Or another dataframe?

Comment: The output derived from the code provided by Maiasaura below produces a list of tables which is useful. I'd love to make sure I know which Displacement is associated with each of those tables in the list - i.e. use Mutate() from dplyr to add an additional column that lists the timestamp of the associated Displacement for each of the tables.

Comment: I managed to figure that part out - easy to add columns using Mutate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Install both packages with install.packages() if you don't have them.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

hostility <- c("Displacement") # add other actions as necessary 

# Now we grab the positions where such hostile events occur
# In your example this is only position 2
pos <- which(df$Action %in% hostility)

# This function will take a position,
# then look 600 seconds forward for 
# rows for actions by Individual2

grab_data <- function(pos) {
  i2 <- as.character(df[pos, ]$Individual2)
  start <- df[pos, ]$Time
  df2 <- df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Time <= (start + 600)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(Individual1 == i2) %>% 
    mutate(actor = i2)
  df2
}

# Now we can "apply" this list of positions to the function. This applies the
# argument on the left (the positions) to the function and returns the output as
# data.frames
map(pos, grab_data)
```

Comment: Brilliant - I think is exactly what I was trying to do @Maiasaura!